# Excel Load list of files in a folder to worksheets with contents on click

Tags: excel, vba

Good day.

I am looking for a solution for a problem, where in i have hundreds of CSV files located in a folder/nested folders.

I am trying to write a VBA script, which loads the list of files in this directory to Excel's work sheet-1 as soft links to each files. when a link is clicked, i am expecting the file contents to be loaded to worksheet 2, which would be used for further reporting purposes.

I have tried writing a VB script to extract the list of folder contents, however, i couldn't get them converted to soft links and loading the file contents. Any suggestions on how (else) could this be achieved ?

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be 2 parts of code. First code will go to a module to list names of the files in the folder and addresses. First column will be names, second column will be addresses

```
Sub ListFiles()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook '<-- Master workbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Sheet you store file names and addresses
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\youfolderaddress")

    i = 1
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Path
        i = i + 1
    Next objFile

End Sub
```

Second part will go to worksheet where you store the list of files and we are going to use workshet selection change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim newBook As Workbook
Dim newSheet As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook '<- Master workbook with all list etc.
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Sheet that contains the list
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2") '<-- Sheet that will display csv content


If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Value <> "" Then '2 is the number of the column that contains file addresses
    ws2.Cells.ClearContents

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Target.Value
    Set newBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set newSheet = newBook.ActiveSheet

    newSheet.Cells.Copy

    ws2.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    newBook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I had been expecting to write some code, so was running through the learning curve of VBA. But your suggestion. sorry the solution is perfect for my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use event handlers. I assume that you are able to load the names into sheet 1 and set a range variable equal to the resulting range of names. You can then use the selection change event to trigger your loading code using something like the following (in the sheet1 code module). Clicking on a cell containing a file name will cause that name to be displayed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim fnames As Range
    Set fnames = Range("fnames") 'adjust to match your code
    If Union(Target, fnames).Address = fnames.Address And _
       Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox Target.Value 'replace this by code to load csv in sheet 2
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: (I fixed a typo after my original answer)

Answer (score 1):

With this code you can, with a default directory, retreive the list of file and add on sheet with the list (linked) of this file.
You can change this code with your to select the different directory

```
Sub ListAllFile()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add

     'Get the folder object associated with the directory
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\Code\Excel")
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "The files found in " & objFolder.Name & "are:"

     'Loop through the Files collection
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Select
        Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=objFile.Name
    Next

     'Clean up!
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```